# How can I correct the Internal Server Error 500 on Forms Authenticated WebRequest in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, forms-authentication, webrequest

This question seems to have been asked before in a variety of terms, so I'll try to be succinct in my particular application.

We're trying to implement the Lucene search indexer on our Intranet which is using Forms based authentication against our domain (using LDAP).

I've followed a number of examples online that all end up pointing to a 500 error; however, this one seems to have have the right approach: [Forms Auth Test in C#](http://www.ksingla.net/2006/08/sample_forms_authentication_test_in_csharp/)

That said, I had to modify the code to reflect my own logon form and server address:

```
HttpWebRequest request = null;
HttpWebResponse response = null;
StreamReader sr = null;

String originalUri = "http://localhost:18843/default.aspx";

// Request page protected by forms authentication.
// This request will get a 302 to login page
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Requesting : " + originalUri);
request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(originalUri);
request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Found)
{
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Response: 302 ");
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
}
else
{
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Response status is " + response.StatusCode + ". Expected was Found");
}

// Get the url of login page from location header
String locationHeader = response.GetResponseHeader("Location");
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Location header is " + locationHeader);

// Request login page
String loginPageUrl = "http://localhost:18843" + locationHeader;
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Requesting " + loginPageUrl);
request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(loginPageUrl);
request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Response: 200 ");
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
}
else
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Response status is " + response.StatusCode + ". Expected was OK");
}

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Parsing login page to create post message");

sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
String loginResponse = sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Close();

String eventTargetVar = "__EVENTTARGET=";
String eventTargetValue = "";
String eventArgumentVar = "__EVENTARGUMENT=";
String eventArgumentValue = "";

String viewStateVar = "__VIEWSTATE=";
String viewStateSearchString = "name=\"__VIEWSTATE\" id=\"__VIEWSTATE\" value=\"";
int viewStateStartIndex = loginResponse.IndexOf(viewStateSearchString);
loginResponse = loginResponse.Substring(viewStateStartIndex +    viewStateSearchString.Length);
String viewStateValue = Uri.EscapeDataString(loginResponse.Substring(0, loginResponse.IndexOf("\" />")));
loginResponse = loginResponse.Substring(loginResponse.IndexOf("\" />"));

String lcSearchStr = "input name=";
int lcSearchIndex = 0;

// Look for logon control id
// Use any valid username and password

lcSearchIndex = loginResponse.IndexOf(lcSearchStr);
//I repeated the search here because the first instance returned my Master Page Search Box
lcSearchIndex = loginResponse.IndexOf(lcSearchStr, lcSearchIndex+1);
loginResponse = loginResponse.Substring(lcSearchIndex + lcSearchStr.Length + 1);
String userNameVar = Uri.EscapeDataString(loginResponse.Substring(0, loginResponse.IndexOf("\""))) + "=";
String userNameValue = "[username]"; //redacted for security

lcSearchIndex = loginResponse.IndexOf(lcSearchStr);
loginResponse = loginResponse.Substring(lcSearchIndex + lcSearchStr.Length + 1);
String passwordVar = Uri.EscapeDataString(loginResponse.Substring(0, loginResponse.IndexOf("\""))) + "=";
String passwordValue = "[userpassword]"; //redacted for security

lcSearchStr = "type=\"submit\" name=";
lcSearchIndex = loginResponse.IndexOf(lcSearchStr);
loginResponse = loginResponse.Substring(lcSearchIndex + lcSearchStr.Length + 1);
String loginButtonVar = Uri.EscapeDataString(loginResponse.Substring(0, loginResponse.IndexOf("\""))) + "=";
String loginButtonValue = "Login";

String eventValidationVar = "__EVENTVALIDATION=";
String eventValSearchString =
"name=\"__EVENTVALIDATION\" id=\"__EVENTVALIDATION\" value=\"";
int eventValStartIndex = loginResponse.IndexOf(eventValSearchString);
loginResponse = loginResponse.Substring(eventValStartIndex + eventValSearchString.Length);

String eventValidationValue =
Uri.EscapeDataString(loginResponse.Substring(0, loginResponse.IndexOf("\" />")));
```

/* Building out the form, it's worth noting my "actual" form inputs, repeated here for clarity and insight */
//BEGIN actual logon.aspx form

```
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"__VIEWSTATE\" id=\"__VIEWSTATE\" value=\"[viewstate data]" />
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR\" id=\"__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR\" value=\"[viewstategen]\" /> 
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"__EVENTVALIDATION\" id=\"__EVENTVALIDATION\" value=\"[val]" />
<input name=\"ctl00$txtSearch\" type=\"text\" value=\"Search Site\" id=\"ctl00_txtSearch\" class=\"header-search-txtSearch\" style=\"width:85%;\" />
<input type=\"image\" name=\"ctl00$btnSearch\" id=\"ctl00_btnSearch\" class=\"header-search-lnkSearch\" src=\"images/header-search-MagGlass.png\" border=\"0\" />
<input name=\"ctl00$MainContent$txtUsername\" type=\"text\" id=\"ctl00_MainContent_txtUsername\" style=\"width:60%;\" />                
<input name=\"ctl00$MainContent$txtPassword\" type=\"password\" id=\"ctl00_MainContent_txtPassword\" style=\"width:60%;\" />
<input id=\"ctl00_MainContent_chkPersist\" type=\"checkbox\" name=\"ctl00$MainContent$chkPersist\" />
<input type=\"submit\" name=\"ctl00$MainContent$btnLogin\" value=\"Login\" id=\"ctl00_MainContent_btnLogin\" style=\"float: right;\" />
```

//END logon.aspx

```
String postString = eventTargetVar + eventTargetValue;                  
postString += "&" + eventArgumentVar + eventArgumentValue;
postString += "&" + viewStateVar + viewStateValue;
postString += "&" + "ctl00$txtSearch=Search Site";
postString += "&" + "ctl00$btnSearch=images/header-search-MagGlass.png";
postString += "&" + userNameVar + userNameValue;
postString += "&" + passwordVar + passwordValue;
postString += "&" + "ctl00$MainContent$chkPersist=";
postString += "&" + loginButtonVar + loginButtonValue;
postString += "&" + eventValidationVar + eventValidationValue;

//
// Do a POST to login.aspx now
// This should result in 302 with Set-Cookie header
//
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("POST request to http://localhost:18843" + locationHeader);
request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:18843" + locationHeader);
request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
byte[] requestData = encoding.GetBytes(postString);
request.ContentLength = requestData.Length;

Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(requestData, 0, requestData.Length);
requestStream.Close();

//
//ERROR 500 occurs on following line
response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Found)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Response: 302 ");
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
}
else
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Response status is " + response.StatusCode + ". Expected was Found");
}

locationHeader = response.GetResponseHeader("Location");
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Location header is " + locationHeader);
String cookie = response.GetResponseHeader("Set-Cookie");
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Set-Cookie header is " + cookie);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("");

//
// Send request to originalUri with the cookie
// We should be able to see originalUri contents
//
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Requesting http://localhost:18843" + locationHeader + " with cookie");
request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:18843" + locationHeader);
request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, cookie);

response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Response: 200 ");
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
}
else
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Response status is " + response.StatusCode + ". Expected was OK");
}
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("");

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Contents of " + originalUri);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("");

sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
sr.Close();
```

SO there you have it. In the comments on this fellas blog, it's said that others have got the 500 error as well, but there doesn't seem to be a remedy. I'm attempting to load in fiddler to see what's up, but have been unsuccessful so far.

I really hope it's something I'm just doing dumb and can be corrected quickly. Thanks all!

Comment: forms Authentication or not is it possible that since you are going against your `LDAP / AD` why not use `PrincipalContext` I use it all the time

Comment: Not sure if I understand you; but the login from the actual page works just fine using PrincipalContext, etc. 

This is from code to enable the Lucene Search Indexer to parse and index each page, so it's having trouble connecting to each site page because authentication is required. I'm not sure how I can execute a WebRequest using PrincipalContext.

Comment: ok from each site does it authenticate based on the users initial login to the main form for example..? if so then you can capture the username or userid stored in a HttpContext.Current.Session variable and check against that if it's just checking to see if the user is in the Domain LDAP or ActiveDirectory..